# What is the best way to compare an actual value from an expected value on a linear model?

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I'm comparing the cost of dialysis in each country. The x axis is health expenditure per capita. The y axis is cost of dialysis per patient. As you will see, this incredibly produces a near liner model. Except, for the U.S. Although some would expect the U.S. to be above the model line, the U.S. is well below the expected value.

What is the best way to statistically demonstrate this for a medical journal publication? Can you say an actual value is statistically different than an expected value? [image: graph]

Comment: You can create a model (ex. linear fit) and calculate the $1\sigma$ variance. The USA data point is maybe 2-3 $\sigma$ away from the mean. You should ask here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/ since the question is off-topic on this site.